# How to get a scheduled lambda to run again unless specified in callback

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which can take longer to complete than 5 mins. It uses a scheduled cron trigger but in the event it doesn't complete, I would like the lambda to run again unless the callback provided to the handler is called to mark it complete. Is there a way to do this with scheduled triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Step functions, where the function doing long-running job can be put in retry block. Sample as follows:

```
  {
   "Comment": "function comment",
   "StartAt": "Step1",
   "States": {
      "Step1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "place your lambda ARN",
      "Next": "Step2"
    },
   "Step2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "place your lambda ARN",
      "Catch": [ {
        "ErrorEquals": [ "your error thrown from lambda like job not completed" ],
       "Next": "Step2"   //here it retries the function again
     }],
    "End": true
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda [limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) the maximum execution time of a single invocation to 5 minutes. we should write Lambda functions that perform long-running tasks as recursive functions.

use **context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()**
When your function is invoked, the context object allows you to find out how much time is left in the current invocation.

Suppose you have an expensive task that can be broken into small tasks that can be processed in batches. At the end of each batch, use context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() to check if there’s still enough time to keep processing. Otherwise, recurse and pass along the current position so the next invocation can continue from where it left off like as follows:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
let position = event.position || 0;

do {
    ... // process the tasks in small batches that can be completed 
    in, 
    say, less than 10s
    // when there's less than 10s left, stop
   } while (position < totalTaskCount && 
   context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 10000);

  if (position < totalTaskCount) {
    let newEvent = Object.assign(event, { position });
    recurse(newEvent);
    callback(null, `to be continued from [${position}]`);
  } else {
   callback(null, "all done");
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use trigger in this case. Here is how I would handle it.

Create a Kinesis Stream and Lambda.

In the Lambda do the smallest operation possible and finish it. Don't make the task bigger or taking longer time.

At the end of your code, post an event to Kinesis Stream. 
Add a trigger to your Lambda from the Stream.

It will make a continious loop asynchronously chugging your business logic.

Problem with using trigger is, even if your previous run is not completed, it will trigger your next run, So there are chances  two instances of the lambda could run in parallel.

Hope it helps.